# How Loop Through Index Based on Lists of Start and End Values While Assigning New Values to New Column

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

short version: I need to loop through the criteria dataframe to assign values with a column of start values, end values, and assignment values. The second dataframe possesses the values I need to assign a the "assignment values" to in a column.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I'm working from two separate dataframes, created from imported CSVs. One imported CSV file possesses the Start, End and Assignment Categories. The second contains the actual values I need to assign the list of values I need to assign categories too. In general, I know this seems weird to ask, but this is how I got the data and it would take a lot more time to go through by hand on excel and label of separate categories over the large number list given.

For the sake of expediency, I created value names that match index numbers but in my real file, the names do not match the index numbers.

This is the criteria data frame with my start, end and assignment values

```
Start     End     Category
1          15       Dog
16         19       Rabbit
20         23       Bat
```

This is what the current data frame I want to work on looks like

```
    Items      
    Item 1        
    Item 2        
    Item 3        
    Item 4        
    Item 5        
    .
    .
    .
    Item 16       
    Item 17       
    Item 18       
    Item 19       
    Item 20       
    Item 21       
    Item 22
```

This is what I'd want the data frame to become

```
Items       New Column
Item 1        Dog
Item 2        Dog
Item 3        Dog
Item 4        Dog
Item 5        Dog
.
.
.
Item 16       Rabbit
Item 17       Rabbit
Item 18       Rabbit
Item 19       Rabbit
Item 20       Bat
Item 21       Bat
Item 22       Bat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve your problem is by applying new value to the `New Column` while filtering your first dataframe over the range created by `Start` and `End` of each row values like this example:

```
import pandas as pd


def assign_value(row, df):
    index = int(row['Items'].replace('Item ', ''))
    # Check if index is in the df start ranges
    _df = df.loc[[index in elm for elm in df['Range'].values]]
    if not _df.empty:
        return _df.iloc[0]['Category']
    return None


start_rows = [(1, 15, 'Dog'), (16, 19, 'Rabbit'), (20, 23, 'Bat')]
df_start = pd.DataFrame(start_rows, columns=['Start', 'End', 'Category'])
# Create a new column with a range from start to end + 1
df_start['Range'] = df_start.apply(lambda row: range(row['Start'], row['End'] + 1), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame([f'Item {elm}' for elm in range(1, 23)], columns=['Items'])
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda row: assign_value(row, df_start), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Items New Column
0    Item 1        Dog
1    Item 2        Dog
2    Item 3        Dog
3    Item 4        Dog
4    Item 5        Dog
5    Item 6        Dog
6    Item 7        Dog
7    Item 8        Dog
8    Item 9        Dog
9   Item 10        Dog
10  Item 11        Dog
11  Item 12        Dog
12  Item 13        Dog
13  Item 14        Dog
14  Item 15        Dog
15  Item 16     Rabbit
16  Item 17     Rabbit
17  Item 18     Rabbit
18  Item 19     Rabbit
19  Item 20        Bat
20  Item 21        Bat
21  Item 22        Bat
```

Or you can simply (if your start dataframe is small) you can use this assign function:

```
def assign_value(row, df):
    for _, elm in df.iterrows():
        index = int(row['Items'].replace('Item ', ''))
        if index in range(elm['Start'], elm['End'] + 1):
            return elm['Category']
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

On the criteria dataframe, make a column in which each cell is a list with size `end - start` ( the content of the list doesn't matter ). Then [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the dataframe and assign the ( now exploded ) category column to your second dataframe.

```
criteria_df['count'] = criteria_df['Start'].combine(criteria_df['End'], lambda x,y: list(range(x,y + 1)))
criteria_df = criteria_df.explode('count')
second_df['New Column'] = criteria_df['Category']
```

Or if you don't like lambda:

```
def generate_list(start_index, end_index):
    return list(range(start_index, end_index + 1))

criteria_df['count'] = criteria_df['Start'].combine(criteria_df['End'], generate_list)
criteria_df = criteria_df.explode('count')
second_df['New Column'] = criteria_df['Category']
```

This approach assumes that your ranges are sorted and that there are no gaps in between the ranges.